# Dask dataframes known_divisions and performance

Tags: python, dask

I have several files whose with a column called `idx` and I would like to use it as index. The dataframe obtained has about 13M row. I know that I can read and assign index in this way (which is slow ~40 s)

```
df = dd.read_parquet("file-*.parq")
df = df.set_index("idx")
```

or in this other way (which is quick ~40 ms)

```
df = dd.read_parquet("file-*.parq", index = "idx")
```

A simple operation as calculate the length is ~4x faster with the second method. What I don't understand is

- on the first case `df.known_divisions` returns `True` while on the second is `False`. I expected the opposite behaviour. I then did several operations on top of `df` and the without a known_division I'm always obtaining better performance. I'm scratching my head to figure out if this is happening on purpose or not.
- the number of partitions is the number of files. How can I set a different number of partitions?

**UPDATE**
It is not just calculating `len` which is faster. In my calculation I create 4 new dataframes using groupby, apply and join several times and these are the timings

```
|                  |Load and reindex (s)|Load with index (s)|
|:-----------------|-------------------:|------------------:|
| load             |            12.5000 |            0.0124 |
| grp, apply, join |            11.4000 |            6.2700 |
| compute()        |           146.0000 |          125.0000 |
| TOTAL            |           169.9000 |          131.2820 |
```

Comment: To the update: it will depend on what exactly your groupby etc., are, whether you do several computations in a single compute (to amortize the shuffle time cost) and what the memory cost of the shuffle is. Often, people may choose to persist after the set_index, if there is enough RAM to work with.

Comment: I will check persist and ask a more specific question about performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the first method, dask is loading the data, and partitioning the rows by the value of your chosen column (which involves shuffling all of the on-disc chunks) before doing any of the calculation you have asked for. In the case of calculating the length, this is all wasted time, as a knowledge of the index divisions doesn't help at all with that, but further computations involving that index (e.g., join operations) would be much faster.

In the second version, you are asserting that your chosen column is the index, but dask does not shuffle the data without you explicitly asking for it. If it happens to have statistics saved in the parquet metadata, and the max/min of each parquet chunk is such, that they form a monotonic series (i.e., all of the values of 'idx' in the second chunk are greater than all of the values in the first, etc.), then you will have known divisions and optimized performance for certain operations involving the index as before. If those conditions are not met, you have the index column set, but the divisions are not known - which, again, is totally fine for calculating the length.